# Can't add a new column using migration in laravel 5 to table with too many data

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

I'm trying to add a new column to my "users" table in postgres, I'm using Laravel 5.1, the new column would be a timestamp with default to "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", this is my migration file:

```
public function up(){
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->timestamp('last_activity_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    });
}
```

My user's table has over 20,000 records

When running php artisan migrate it just gets stuck, nothing happens, the server reponds, postgres responds but the user's table seems to be locked, I have to restart the server.

The problem happened in 2 different servers, dev and prod, in prod I was asked to confirm to run the migration and then it just gets stuck

I made some more tests, I removed the default value and used nullable()

```
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->timestamp('last_activity_at')->nullable();
    });
```

When the migration is running I checked postgres pg_stat_activity and it returns this record:

```
datid            | 16384
datname          | apiprod
pid              | 14183
usesysid         | 16386
usename          | apiprod
application_name | 
client_addr      | ::1
client_hostname  | 
client_port      | 49618
backend_start    | 2017-07-04 18:54:19.143425+02
xact_start       | 2017-07-04 18:54:19.165856+02
query_start      | 2017-07-04 18:54:19.165872+02
state_change     | 2017-07-04 18:54:19.165873+02
waiting          | t
state            | active
backend_xid      | 
backend_xmin     | 14765396
query            | alter table "users" add column "last_activity_at" timestamp(0) without time zone null
```

Seems like it's waiting to get `access exclusive` lock, I checked the locks table but it doesn't return any record.

Comment: hmmm its just a suggestion : create new column without default value, and after migrate and column creation try to fill value of column

Comment: Can't use refresh since it's a production server

Answer (score 1):

I think your migration file meet an internal error 
when we use migration sometime it stuck

Use this command:

php artisan migrate:refresh OR php artisan migrate:rollback

Don't delete the column manually
And then migrate the file again